# Parsing JSON objects that change with each API query

Tags: python, json

I have some JSON that I'm trying to parse using python. The problem is that it's returned from an API that generates a unique number in the returned JSON each time, which makes it difficult for me to figure out how to parse.

Below is an example: everything is uniform in the returned JSON except one object (in this example, "258") changes with each result (i.e., to 35432, 2848585, etc.).

In short, I can't write `data = json['data']['258']['name']` in my code, since the "258" changes each time.

There's always one item in `data`, so I tried `json['data'][0]['name']`, but that didn't work.

Is there a way that I can parse JSON where there is an object that is changing, given that its always the only object in `['data']`? Perhaps there's some code that can just search the JSON result for `name:"matt"`?

```
   {
        data: {
            258: {
                name: "matt"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain there is ever only one object within the "data" tag, you can do this:

```
import json

# Convert the JSON data into a Python dictionary
d = json.loads(json_data)

# Check if the data tag is present
if "data" in d:

    # Loop through all the inner keys (in your case just the single integer key)
    for key in d["data"]:

        # Use the "key" variable in your path
        print d["data"][key]["name"]
```

For searching through the structure:

```
def dict_search(key, value, p_dictionary):
    """ Searches for a specific key, value combination within a multilevel python dictionary """
    for k in p_dictionary:
        if k == key and p_dictionary[k] == value:
            print "Found %s, %s!" % (key, value)
            return p_dictionary
        # Check if inner dictionary is found
        if type(p_dictionary[k]) is dict:
            print "Using recursion to check the inner dictionary.."
            dict_search(key, value, p_dictionary[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this to work by following @Jacob-IT to use `json.loads` and `d['data'].keys()[0]`.